# React/Redux how to access the state in the networkservice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have created a Network service component which deals with the API call. I want to retrieve state from other components which update the `store`.
Im having trouble getting the state so I started using Redux, but I havent used Redux before and still trying to find a way to pass the state to the `NetworkService`. Any help would be great, thanks!

Here is my NetworkService.js

```
import RequestService from './RequestService';
import store from '../store';

const BASE_URL = 'api.example.com/';
const REGION_ID = //Trying to find a way to get the state here

// My attempt to get the state, but this unsubscribes and
// doesnt return the value as it is async
let Updated = store.subscribe(() => {
   let REGION_ID = store.getState().regionId;
}) 

class NetworkService {

    getForecast48Regional(){
        let url =`${BASE_URL}/${REGION_ID }`;
        return RequestService.getRequest(url)
    }
}

export default new NetworkService();
```

store.js

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';

const initialState = {
  regionId: 0
};
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  if(action.type === "REGIONAL_ID") {
     return {
        regionId: action.regionId
      };
    }
    return state;
}
const store = createStore(reducer);

export default store;
```

My folder heirarchy looks like this:

```
-App
----Components
----NetworkService
----Store
```

Comment: why don't you pass the value you want as an argument to `getForecast48Regional`

Comment: The problem is once I get more Api calls I will have to pass argument to all of them and it won't be consistent.

Comment: @azium is right, you better try to keep API calls unaware of store's shape, because usually, API call needs a few parameters only, while the store contains all the information that's relevant to UI application, not 100% business logic stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not import store directly. Use thunks/sagas/whatever for these reasons.

- **NetworkService** should not know about **anything** below.
- **Thunks** know only about **NetworkService** and plain redux **actions**.
- **Components** know only about **thunks** and **store** (not store itself, but Redux's selectors, `mapStateToProps`, `mapDispatchToProps`).
- **Store** knows about plain redux **actions** only.

Knows - e.g. `import`'s.

```
//////////// NetworkService.js
const networkCall = (...args) => fetch(...) // say, returns promise

//////////// thunks/core/whatever.js
import { networkCall } from 'NetworkService'

const thunk = (...args) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch(startFetch(...args))

  const componentData = args
  // I'd suggest using selectors here to pick only required data from store's state
  // instead of passing WHOLE state to network layer, since it's a leaking abstraction
  const storeData = getState()

  networkCall(componentData, storeData)
    .then(resp => dispatch(fetchOk(resp)))
    .catch(err => dispatch(fetchFail(err)))
}

//////////// Component.js
import { thunk } from 'thunks/core/whatever'

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  doSomeFetch: thunk,
}

const Component = ({ doSomeFetch }) =>
  <button onClick={doSomeFetch}>Do some fetch</button>

// store.subscribe via `connect` from `react-redux`
const ConnectedComponent = connect(..., mapDispatchToProps)(Component)
```

Comment: Yeah, I read about thunk but didn't understand it completely, thanks for the answer, will be using this method.

Comment: After reading more on thunk, it seems I would need to restructure the way I make API calls. Is there no way to make the `NetworkService` receive the state?... I think your method would mean changing the whole NetworkService

Comment: @SGhaleb I've updated thunk example. Does it fit your vision of the API-calls layer now?